# Kivy: How set up item Drop-Down

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I need to set up dynamically list in *Drop-Down*. For setting I want to use constructor of class *DiscDropDown*, which is decendant of class *DropDown*. (It means, that want to set up value for variable *li_disc* in class *DiscDropDown*). Instance of this class is not part of python code, because I use *Builder*.
How do I realize it in next code?

```
    Builder.load_string('''

    <Save_As>:
        drop_down: drop_down
        orientation:'vertical'

        DiscDropDown:
            id: drop_down
            size_hint: None,None
            height: 50

        Button:
            id: bt_delete_file
            disabled: False
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: 250

            text: 'Fictive'

    ''')

    class DiscDropDown(DropDown):
        def __init__(self, **kwarg):
            super(DiscDropDown, self).__init__(**kwarg)

            self.dropdown = DropDown()

# I wanted to set up value Button.text during creation Buttons
            for name in li_disc:
                btn = Button(text = name, size_hint_y=None, height=44)
                btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))
                self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

            mainbutton = Button(text='Disc', size_hint=(None, None),size = (50,50))
            mainbutton.bind(on_release = self.dropdown.open)
            self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))
            self.add_widget(mainbutton)


    class Save_As(BoxLayout):
     #   drop_down = ObjectProperty()
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Save_As, self).__init__( **kwargs)


            return

    class ExplorerApp(App):

        def build(self):

            self.save_as = Save_As()

            return self.save_as

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ExplorerApp().run()
```

For solving my problem I used next process for setting value variable *Button.text*:

```
class Save_As(BoxLayout):
    drop_down = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        li_disc = ['aa','bb','cc']
        super(Save_As, self).__init__( **kwargs)

#       I set up Button.text here
        for i in range(0,3):
            self.children[1].dropdown.children[0].children[i].text = li_disc[i]

        return
```

I think that my solution isn't ideal, cann you recommend me better process?

Comment: I see that it is shown in dropdown, what is the problem?

Comment: @eyllanesc I added some details to my guestion. Cann you see it.